# IIS automatically deletes SSL Certificate after installation on Azure VM

Tags: azure, iis, ssl, https, windows-server-2012-r2

I try to install an ssl certificate (signed by thawtee) in the IIS 8.5.
I do this like I always do on my other windows servers (which are not running in Azure).

However the "Complete Certificate Request" will be successfully completed and the cert is listed correctly. But if reload the list or switch to other tab and return to certs, the cert is deleted.

This occurs only in vm's which are provided by Azure. So I try install the cert first in the cloudservice where my vm is running. The upload is successful, but when I try to install it in IIS the same issue occurs.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply caused by the fact that you attempted to install a wrong certificate,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/06/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-77-588-510-0-after-installing-it-why/

You will have to generate a proper PFX file out of the files you received from the CA, and then resolve this issue.